# Is it possible to run my meteor tests in docker?

Tags: testing, meteor, docker, jasmine

Once I've built my container with my Meteor app in it, I'd really like to be able to go

`docker run me/myapp velocity test-app --ci --once --settings settings-test.json`

And have it exit with `0` if successful, in which case I'll push it to docker hub, deploy it somewhere etc.

However when I try this it just hangs:

```
[velocity] is in continuous integration mode
[velocity] mocha is starting a mirror at http://localhost:56381/.
[velocity] *** Meteor Tools is installing *** 
This takes a few minutes the first time.
[velocity] You can see the mirror logs at: tail -/app/.meteor/local/log/mocha.log
```

I'm using jasmine as per https://github.com/meteor-velocity/velocity-examples (I started with Mocha, but switched over to see if it made any difference).

Inspecting my `.meteor/local/log` files I find `jasmine-client- unit.log` has this at the bottom:

```
WARN [watcher]: [39m Pattern "/app/tests/jasmine/client/unit/**/*-+(stub|stubs|mock|mocks).+(js|coffee|litcoffee|coffee.md)" does not match any file.
WARN [karma]: [39m No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
INFO [karma]: [39m Karma v0.13.9 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: [39m Starting browser Chrome
ERROR [launcher]: [39m No binary for Chrome browser on your platform.
Please, set "CHROME_BIN" env variable
Parent process ( 725 ) is dead! Exiting jasmine-client-unit
```

Chrome clearly isn't going to be available in docker - should phantomjs be installed at this point and specified as a the running option? I would have expected this to be the case by default if the `--ci` option has been specified?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally you should be using a real browser such as Chrome or Firefox to do automated testing, not PhantomJS. You can run browsers headlessly using [Xvfb](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml).

These might be useful:

http://codeutopia.net/blog/2013/07/13/headless-chromefirefox-testing-in-nodejs-with-selenium-and-xvfb/

http://elementalselenium.com/tips/38-headless

Selenium is the way to go for testing. IMO the best setup would be to use a CI server like Jenkins or TeamCity, with Xvfb installed, and have a test/deploy shell script in Jenkins such as:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -ex

cd $WORKSPACE
export VELOCITY_CI=1

meteor --test --settings $WORKSPACE/.deploy-staging/settings.json

cd .deploy-staging
mupx setup
mupx deploy
```

(Note that Xvfb is not implemented here, though). This test is not entirely working, I have yet to jump into Xvfb myself, though I know this is the right direction.

I'm using [mupx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mupx) to deploy my apps, which automatically creates a Docker instance on the remote server for me and handles deployment completely.

Comment: Is it possible to do such real browser testing in a CI environment, other than using saucelabs / similar?

Comment: Thanks - this looks like just what I was looking for. I haven't quite got it working end to end yet, but a massive step in the right direction. Plus pleasantly circleci comes with Xvfb available https://circleci.com/docs/environment#browsers

Comment: @Joshua Oh man, that's awesome! Too bad CircleCI only supports GitHub at the moment (I'm using GitLab).